# Should you split up implementation of member function templates and normal member functions?

Tags: c++, header, implementation

If you have a class that contains both member function templates and normal member functions like so:

```
struct Foo
{
    void normal();
    template<typename T>
    void templated();
};
```

With **code maintainability** in mind, what is the most efficient way of structuring the implementation of these member functions? With class templates, I usually put the implementation of member functions in a `.inl` file that I then include at the bottom of the header so that I still seperate the declaration code and the implementation code. I currently do the same with normal classes that contain template functions, but I'm unsure of where to implement the normal member functions. Putting them in a `.cpp` file obviously works, but it splits up the implementation of the member functions into two files, which isn't very intuitive. Functions and functions templates aren't neccessarily that different in the type of work they perform, so it's often not immediately clear if a given function implementation you're looking for is in the `.inl` file or the `.cpp` file, meaning you have to scan both of them.

Is the most **long-term efficent** solution to just put the normal function implementations into the `.inl` file as well, and just skip `.cpp` files entirely for classes that contain templates? Is there any advantage compile-wise that you miss out on if you don't put the normal functions in `.cpp` files?

Comment: Well, obviously the usual rule is that you recompile on any change to the header/`.inl` but not for the `.cpp`; is there anything beyond that here that isn’t an opinion?